# How do I restrict my uploaded files to accept only zip files ?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, file-type

Good morning guys. I have created two php files that successfully upload files to my server. One file is the visual part for my website called upload.php and the other is the upload file part called upload_file.php.
the code to upload my files is

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./medetrax_backup/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");
```

This works perfectly however it lets me upload any file type. So since I want to only allow zipped folders i tried this if statement.

```
if($type=="application/zip" ){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./medetrax_backup/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");
echo "<div id='mes'> File upload complete</div>";}
else{
echo "<div id='mes'>This file type cannot be uploaded. Only zip folders with the naming convention INITIAL.DATE.TIME are accepted</div>";
}
where $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
```

But now it doesnt let me upload any files not even zipped ones. So what do i need to put in my if statement to only allow zipped folders to be upload? And if your really good guys what do i need to put in my if statement to allow only zipped foleders with the naming convention of USERINITIAL.DATE.TIME or USERINITIAL/DATE/TIME or can this not be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this solution

```
$fileName = strtolower($fileName);
$allowedExts = array('zip');
$extension = explode(".", $fileName);   
$extension = end($extension);
if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
   //move file to custom folder
}
```

- IMPORTANT *
  Never not use from mime time for identification file type,because it bypass with tamper data.
  Best way:
  Move your all uploaded file into out of public_html,and Always rename file name,when you want upload  this.
  And so,save uploaded file name into database,and read file from one php file,for example:

  read.php?id=5
  in your read.php file,you should get id number and search on database for it,then,return file name from db and download or read this file with read.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Due to some discussion on this thread, heres a little bonus info.
Generally speaking, it's really, really hard to determine if a file is actually the kind of file we want. You can check the mime type, which can be modified by the client. You can check the file extension, which can also be modified by the client- Vice versa.
You can even check the first few lines of a file, which typically contains some sort of header, explaining what kind of file we'r handling. But still then, the file might be modified by some evil genius making the executing program buffer overflow or exploits some library used, to open/view/taste/throw the file.

---

Lets check both file extension and mime.

First, the extension.

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$isZipExtension = ( $extension == "zip" ? true : false );
```

On your "$_FILES" array, you have a index called "Type".

Now, you would like to restrict the upload to only accept Zip files.
Theres a few types defining a potential zip file. So lets create an array.

```
$zipTypes = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 
'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
```

Now, lets check if the type uploaded, is part of the array.

```
$isZipFile = in_array( $_FILES['file']["type"], $zipTypes );
```

If, the file is in the array, do your upload process.

```
if( $isZipFile && $isZipExtension) {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./medetrax_backup/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");
echo "<div id='mes'> File upload complete</div>";
} else {
echo "<div id='mes'>This file type cannot be uploaded. Only zip folders with the naming convention INITIAL.DATE.TIME are accepted</div>";
}
```

All together

```
    $zipTypes = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 
    'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $isZipExtension = ( $extension == "zip" ? true : false );
    $isZipFile = in_array( $_FILES['file']["type"], $zipTypes );

    if( $isZipFile && $isZipExtension) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./medetrax_backup/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");
        echo "<div id='mes'> File upload complete</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div id='mes'>This file type cannot be uploaded. Only zip folders with the naming convention INITIAL.DATE.TIME are accepted</div>";
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Trusting the media type is a bad idea because the client can spoof it. And if they do, they also get to choose the file extension. At least if you just whitelist-check the extension they don't get to choose one they like.

Comment: Id rather want a mix of the two. File extension spoofing can be just as harmfull

Comment: this did not work it goes to the else when i try to upload a zipped file alsoyou did not talk about the naming convention being restricted

Comment: Have you checked the output of the "File type" array index?
As others have pointed out, you should check for the file extension aswell. Or, atleast be sure to add the extension.

Comment: @Jonasm: I really don't see what you mean. What's the point in checking the media type? Even if it satisfies your check, you have accomplished absolutely nothing. How is doing both better than just checking the extension?

Comment: The same goes around with the extension check. No matter if you feel like spoofing the webserver or the client running the executable, you may aswell succeed doing so spoofing a file extension.

Comment: i have copied your code exactly jonas m and it does not work. As i am new to this can you suggest code wise what i should do

Comment: Could you try :   echo $_FILES['file']["type"];   and write the output here in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, you should *never* use the `type` key to check the type of file being uploaded. That's because the value of that key is set by the client and can be trivially spoofed.

What you should be doing instead is checking the file extension (which at least makes sure that no well-configured program on *your* server will treat the upload in an unexpected manner):

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$allowed = ['zip'];
if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    // process the file
}
```

Comment: Jon your code did not work but lead me down the right path so thank you.

Comment: allowed ="zip", if($ext == $allowed)